# running android emulator in windows azure

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-emulator, azure-virtual-machine

Has anyone yet tried running android emulator in windows azure, my research shows that it's not possible.

But that search relies on answers older than a year. Surely things have changed. 
Can anyone one please point to to the right direction?

Comment: It looks like possible now. I managed to start an emulator on a Dv3 series VM with HAXM support.

Comment: @stargater https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240664/running-android-emulator-with-azure-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Still the same. Cannot run an emulator (hardware acceleration) inside the azure VM.