# Running android emulator with Azure windows 10

Tags: android, azure, virtual-machine, emulation

I am trying to run an android emulator on an azure VM running windows, Windows 10 Pro  version 1809 - But I am getting the following error message running the android emulator:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator -AVD androidemulatorapi28
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure the Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine

The hyper-v is enabled:

[image]

And Windows Hypervisor Platform as well:

[image]

The size of the VM is `D2_v3` and Dv3 - series is supposed to support Nested Virtualization. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ded3eee-17cf-4f69-9337-589037436733/using-android-x86-on-azure-virtual-machines?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191202/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-make-android-emulator-run-on-azure-virtual-machine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364841/running-android-emulator-hyper-v-based-on-a-azure-vm-windows-server-2016) are claims about it being so and that android emulator functions. And as I far as I have understood:

[image]

...is part of Dv3 series.

**What could be the problem?**

---

I am able to run an Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V of the Azure Windows VM.

Disabling `Hyper-V` and `Windows Hypervisor Platform`, installing `HAXM` and running I get this error:

[image]

According to the writer of this [medium article](https://medium.com/@everton.rreis/android-emulator-on-azure-vm-fe4df57a6955) and this StackOverflow [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433641/does-azure-allow-app-need-opengl-any-way-to-go-around?source=post_page---------------------------) - A special custom implementation of OpenGL is necessary - because the particular azure VM size doesn't come with a GPU. However, following the steps of the article I get another type of crash - when using the `Mesa3D+LLvmpip version of opengl32.dll` from the authors Github repo, replacing the OpenGL file in system32 and running the android emulator:

[image]

---

I found there was a [gihub repo](https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win#downloads) - distributing Mesa3D and LLvmpip - downloading [mesa3d-19.1.3-release-mingw.exe](https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases) and running the cmd file:

[image]

There is the following message in cmd:

> This deployment utility targets systems without working GPUs and any use case
>   where hardware-accelerated OpenGL is not available. This mainly covers
>   virtual machines in cloud environments and RDP connections. It can be
>   used to replace Microsoft Windows inbox OpenGL 1.1 software render
>   driver with Mesa3D soft pipe, llvmpipe or SWR driver.

...which seems to be a fit for the driver rendering problem.

---

I was able to git rid of all cmd warnings and error by`-avd myandroidemulatorapi28`, and any with of following two flags `-gpu angle_indirect` or `-gpu swiftshader_indirect`. And `set QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none` before running it. The GUI message about the driving issue still comes up and **there is a black screen**.

According to the owner of the mesa-dist-win GitHub repo - he could reproduce the GUI message diver complaint and still run the emulator successfully - when imitating the state of a VM with his machine.

Comment: [The Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-android-emulators-on-windows) state _"You can't run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another VM, such as a VM hosted by VirtualBox, VMWare, or Docker. You must run the Android emulator directly on your system hardware_".
Did you consider using the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/vs/msft-android-emulator/)? Didn't try but maybe it offers better support for nested VM.

Comment: It seems it's outdated and abandoned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864647/running-api-level-24-on-vs-emulator-for-android-hyper-v. There is also a notice on top of the page - that it does not support hardware acceleration.

Comment: Using `GPU Caps Viewer` it says `GL_VENDOR: VMware, Inc`. And android docs also states is not possible.

Comment: Here is a longer discussion about running android emulator on windows vm: https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/issues/26

Comment: I am currently doing a workaround by connecting my visual studio on the windows vm to my Mac (I think both has to be in the same vpn) following this set up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows - allowing me to use android installed on my mac.

Comment: Did you get you Android emu to work on azure vm?

Comment: @Major No I never did!

Comment: thanks. oh well.. ive been trying multiple times and had no chance too.

Comment: btw, if you still need it, I got a luck and have it running on ubuntu using kvm. no hyper v or haxm.

Comment: Adding onto this. I tried for around a week, with Support team and self tries, but I guess it isn't possible to run AVD on azure VDI (Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This is not a solution, this is for sharing details of what I learned after trying out around 10-20 ways:**

- To enable virtualization in azure VDI, you need to enable Hyper-V feature.
- After that you can see in your task manager->Performance that the virtualization is set to `true`.
- If not, try enabling it from command prompt.
  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
- After that virtualization is enabled.
- Now, you won't be able to install Intel HAXM, as there is a race condition between Hyper-V and Intel HAXM for virtualization.
- So, Without Intel HAXM, AVD won't run.
- Without Enabling Virtualization with Hyper-V, there will be just black screen in AVD, and it won't boot.

So, I believe there is no solution to this problem until now, I have search everything on google, stackoverflow. If someone finds a solution, please post it over here.

Answer (score 0):

Im facing the same issue with you using Win10 or Windows Server 2019 for DV3 and EV3 series. But I got it working on ubuntu if you are open for that option. No hyper v or haxm required, it is using KVM

Comment: I was looking to create multi targeted libraries in Xamarin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173464/how-to-multitarget-in-xamarin-forms-with-visual-studio-for-mac
Which is only possible in Visual Studio on Windows:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to the link "https://github.com/intel/haxm".
2. Scroll down to find "Downloads".
3. Download the "haxm-windows_v7_7_1.zip" for windows & haxm-macosx_v7_7_1.zip for macoxs.
4. Install the package and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

They is another android emulator that is working
https://www.sanganakauthority.com/2020/04/run-android-emulator-and-android-studio.html