# Can Visual Studio connected to adb server on other computer run android devices connected to the other computer?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, xamarin, android-emulator, adb

My setup:

I have mac which has the android tools. And a windows virtual machine - which unfortunately [can't run android directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240664/running-android-emulator-with-azure-windows-10). So I have connected them following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows and they are on the same vpn.

I can see the emulators started on my mac and run my xamarin app successfully from the windows machine:

[image]

But when connecting an android device to the mac it won't show up in visual studio on the windows machine. Running `adb devices` on my mac it shows up:

[image]

And I can run apps on it successfully from other frameworks that I have installed on my mac.

Is there some way I can expose the android device for visual studio to find via the adb server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have better luck if you are using ADB over network.

On the computer where you have connected the devices you can run:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Then if you know the IP of the device you can connect from any computer on the same network with:

```
adb connect ip:5555
```

Then it should appear in VS in the device list.

Comment: The `adb connect` never finishes. I am not 100% what the `tcpip` does but note that the mac and the virtual windows machine are on the same vpn. I assume the device also has to be on the same vpn to be able to connect it via i'ts ip address?

Comment: The device needs to be on the same network you are connecting to with your VPN software.

Comment: I'ts an azure vpn. To which I have both the mac and the virtual windows machine connected to. I don't think I can connect a mobile device to it. It's using IKEv2 with encryption.

Comment: Yea, doing it the other way, from the VM to the network the mac and the device is on would be much easier.

Comment: It's just that I would have to go into router settings to open ports I believe. Which is a bit unsafe. And I would also like to able to work where I want.